# htaccess - how to redirect url with params to base url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a page.html with params at the end to the base url without params. I know I am supposed to use mod rewrite but I can't get the rules figured out. Your help will be appreciated.

Here is the scenario:
I tried this in htaccess and this rule didn't work:

```
redirect 301 "/page.html?p=2" http://www.domain.com/page.html
```

I understand from reading other posts on stackoverflow that I should write something like

```
^page\.html$ http://www.domain.com/page.html [QSA,NC,R=301,L]
```

The rules at the end `[QSA,NC,R=301,L]` however are incorrect. I can't figure it out. I simply want to do a 301 for this url with the `p=2` parameter, and no other param.

And then process the remaining rules after this rule for other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ /page.html? [R=301,L]
```